# Trouble reading chars in string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, char

I am trying to load a text file that contains characters and two numbers, something that looks like this

```
5 7
++++M++
+  +  +
++   ++
+  ++ +
+X+++++
```

where the 5 and 7 correspond to number of rows and columns.  I am trying to read this line by line and then translate the numbers into values in an array, however for some reason I fail to even

```
     Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fid));
maze_r = inputFile.nextInt();
maze_c = inputFile.nextInt();
int counter = 0;
   while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){

    rowArray = inputFile.nextLine();
  System.out.print("\n"+rowArray);


     char index;
       for(int ind = 0; ind == (maze_c-1);ind++){

            index = rowArray.charAt(ind);
            System.out.print(index);
            if(index == ' ')
                theMaze[counter][ind] = 0;
            if(index == '+')
                theMaze[counter][ind] = 1;
            if(index == 'M')
                theMaze[counter][ind] = 2;
             if(index == 'X')
                theMaze[counter][ind] = 3;

  }
   }
   System.out.print(Arrays.toString(theMaze));
   }
```

When I do this it prints out the rows as characters but will print a void for the array I have tried to make.  I do not know what I am doing wrong, for some reason it will not compute the for loop in the while loop.  When I wrote like a system.out.print inside the loop nothing printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `counter` is not getting incremented.

Comment: You should really put a little more effort in your indentations. It might actually help you noticing your errors.

Comment: On short algorithm don't hesitate to test it by hand, noting the values and going through the statements. It'll then appear clearly whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The second condition in `for` loop is to be `true` for the loop to continue:

```
ind == (maze_c-1) // ⇒ your loop breaks because ind is not equal to the rvalue
```

It should be changed to:

```
ind < maze_c
```

Treat it as “while” condition.

Answer (score 0):

for(int ind = 0; ind == (maze_c-1);ind++){
your loop condition is wrong, ind==(maze_c-1) is always true,so your code in loop,can't be run,then the result of System.out.print(Arrays.toString(theMaze)) is null